# In python, How can i add a $ symbol just before { in the api endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, string-concatenation

I need to add a $ symbol before the { on each line. how can I do it in python,

Problem: Using python I am reading all the API endpoint from the JSON file before I pass those API endpoints, I need to append a $ symbol just before to the open parenthesis {

Below is the code reads the API endpoint name from JSON file and prints.

```
import json
with open("example.json", "r") as reads: # Reading all the API endpoints  from json file.
    data = json.load(reads)
    print(data['paths'].items())
    for parameters, values in data['paths'].items():
        print(parameters)
```

From the above code, I need to go further to achieve adding a $ symbol next to { before printing it.

Below list i get by reading the json file using python:

```
/API/{id}/one
/{two}/one/three
/three/four/{five}
```

Expected is:

```
/API/${id}/one
/${two}/one/three
/three/four/${five}
```

Comment: `newstring = oldstring.replace('{', '${')`

Comment: Should `${` become `${{`? Or should it stay as `${`?

Comment: `.replace()` will not double-dip.

Comment: It should be ${.

Comment: John Gordon, Thanks. Now i am able to achieve the desired output. below is with open("example.json", "r") as reading:
        data = json.load(reading)
        for path, values in data['paths'].items():
                print(path.replace('{'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.replace()`.

```py
>>> obj="""
... /API/{id}/one
... /{two}/one/three
... /three/four/{five}
... """
>>> newobj = obj.replace('{','${')
>>> print(newobj)

/API/${id}/one
/${two}/one/three
/three/four/${five}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `re` library.

```
for parameters, values in data['paths'].items():
     print(re.sub('{', '${', parameters))
```

For more info on `re`, Go through the doc. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, It's a very helpful module.